# Filtering in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

My RDD has TAB delimited strings in it. I'm trying to filter it: if column 5 contains few strings:

```
filt_data = raw_data.filter(lambda x: '' if len(x.split('\t')) < 5 else "apple" in x.split('\t')[4] or "pear" in x.split('\t')[4] or "berry" in x.split('\t')[4] or "cherry" in x.split('\t')[4])
```

I dont think its very effective solution since i'm doing 4 splits of the same row there. Can some1 show more optimal way of doing it?

And what if i have an array of "fruits". How can i filter my RDD that contains elements from this array? 
Could do something like that `x.split('\t')[4] in array` but it will filter only if an array element is equal to column 5 item, but i need to check if column 5 contains any of the strings in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the lambda function, with a "real" function which will do whatever you like, in an efficient way.
See below a prototype of the suggested solution

```
def efficient_func(line):
    if len(x.split('\t')) < 5:
        return ''
    word = line.split('\t')[4]
    ...

    return ...

filt_data = raw_data.filter(efficient_func)
```

Regarding the 2nd question - I think that using one "if" statement should be better than using several "if" statements.
e.g.

```
fruits_array = ['apple','pear','berry','cherry']
if word in fruits_array:
  do_something (or return some_value)
```

Comment: Thanks! It did speed up the process. Any idea about second question how to filter by array contents?

Comment: If I answered your question please accept it. regarding your 2nd question, I think that it is a good idea, and should work. I've updated my answer to reflect that part as well. Please check if it works for you.